# SQL Server logshipping: Extend the LS_Alert window

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, log-shipping

We have a logshipping setup, where the `LS_Restore` job on the secondary database is switched off every night for the datawarehouse to grab its data. The restore cycle is set to 15 minutes and if `LS_Restore` would kick in, the datawarehouse connection would get severed - the interface therefore switches off `LS_Restore`. When the datawarehouse interface is done, the `LS_Restore` job is turned back on.

However, this window can be longer than one hour (by just ten minutes or there-abouts), and this then triggers the `LS_Alert` job to raise errors.

How can we extend the range on `LS_Alert` to, say, 1,5 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Mo64's answer pointed me in the right direction, the issue is with the alert threshold of the secondary server, not the copy speed on the primary. The link provided by Mo64 did also link to the description of the secondary metadata table in `msdb`. I used [those docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/log-shipping-monitor-secondary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to concoct this update statement:

```
update msdb.dbo.log_shipping_monitor_secondary
set restore_threshold = 120         -- this was 45
where secondary_server = '<your server name here>'
```

Answer (score 1):

update the relevant row and column (backup_threshold (in minutes)) in the log shipping config table

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/log-shipping-monitor-primary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017